# Let VSCode reload a file every X seconds

Tags: visual-studio-code

### Problem statement

On my drive there is a file, which gets updated at intervals of every X seconds. I would like to use VSCode to observe this file, *i.e.*  be able to view it in real time. Despite the file changing on my drive, VSCode does not recognize these changes and will not auto-reload the file. It will keep refreshing the file initially, but then updates to the file will cease to show up in VSCode. However when I just reopen the file, then changes are loaded correctly, meaning the file actually does change on the drive.

### Question

Is possible to achieve this via VSCode?

Currently I am using Auto-Scroll in VSCode, to observe latest additions to the file, but the file does not get reloaded at all after a while. How can I force VSCode to reload the file every X seconds?

Comment: What kind of file is it? It somewhat sounds like a log file, but that is just my guess.

Comment: Your guess is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this [Log Viewer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=berublan.vscode-log-viewer).  Out of the box, it seems to "tail" any .log files (as I tested), but it can be configured with glob patterns as well to work with other files.  You can see in this .gif it loads up all my log statements when I make a request to a local API:

[image: gif showing tailing log feature]

Comment: As far as I can tell, this seems to work well. Updates to the file do not cease after a while (*e.g.* 30 seconds or so). Interestingly enough, I had that extension installed for the very same purpose before, but apparently I did not configure it correctly. Either way, thank you. Accepting answer.